# maven - building a project without explicitly building another (dependent) project

Tags: java, maven

I have two separate maven projects A and B residing in my local repository. A project depends on the jar of B. If I need to build project A successfully, what I do is :

Import both A and B as maven project in Eclipse

- Build project B first (to make the jar available in the m2
  repository)
- Build project A.

**Question :**
Is it possible that instead of explicitly import and building project B, I can only import and build project A. Something which can automatically import and build dependent projects)

Answer (score 1):

Two main possibilities:

- If you are mainly interested in testing, you can checkout both projects into your Eclipse workspace and use "Workspace Resolution", which is a feature of the m2e (Maven) plugin and can be enabled through a right click on the project. It does not make a complete build, but changes in project B will immediately be used by project A as long as you start/handle the  project inside Eclipse.
- If you really need a complete build, think about putting both projects as modules into one multi module project. Then you can build both together and Maven determines the build order. The downside: The projects are now tied together and cannot (at least: should not) be build separately any more.

Comment: Is it possible that I checkout only project A in Eclipse and doing mvn install of that, can somehow bring jar of B into m2 repository.

Comment: Only if you run a build server and a Nexus/Artifactory (which is strongly recommended in any company environment). Then you can build a version of B on the build server, point your settings.xml of Maven to your Nexus/Artifactory and get what you want automatically.

Comment: I have a scenario of 4 projects : A, B, C and D.

 A needs B's jar, B needs C's Jar, C needs D's Jar.

 If I manually import and build the pre-requisites, it will work. I am looking for a solution, (I don't know if its feasible) where I only import project A in eclipse, and do mvn install for only project A, it can bring all B, C, D into m2. 

Basically, I want to avoid the explicit step of importing and building B, C and D.

Comment: I read about the multi-module maven possibility and yes I agree that it will be tight coupling , for which I am also not in favour.

Comment: It is not possible without a builder server and company Nexus. You cannot tell eclipse to build projects that are not in the workspace.

Comment: If you have such a complicated structure, though, I would recommend to run a build server (e.g. Jenkins) and a Nexus to handle all this.